# How to open Firefox and additional Firefox tab by bash in a size of x% of display size?

Tags: bash, firefox, size

The question is related to bash and Linux like Debian; Ubuntu or Linux Mint.

It's known to open a new firefox window by bash on follow way:

```
Firefox
```

It's known to open a new Firefox tab on follow way:

```
Firefox https://stackoverflow.com
```

How to open a new Firefox on a size of x% of display size by bash and without awk?

Comment: Please do not post additional information to your question as **answers**! Instead use the [edit] button to add the information to your original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Open a new Firefox window, with specific size and URL

How I do this, using `xdotool` and `wmctrl`:

```
#!/bin/bash

targetUrl="${1:-https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A1765658+firefox}"
geometry=1200x900+200+120

mkBound() { local refstr=({0..9} _ {A..Z} = {a..z}) tfmt
    printf -v tfmt %8s
    tfmt=(${tfmt// /%s}{,,}{,}) tfmt=${tfmt[*]} tfmt=${tfmt// /-}
    printf -v bound $tfmt ${refstr[RANDOM%64]}{,,}{,,,}{,,,}
}
mkBound
printf -v ffurl "data:text/html;ascii,<head><title>%s</title></head>" $bound

firefox --new-window "$ffurl"

while ffwin=$(wmctrl -l|sed -ne "/$bound/s/ .*$//gp");[[ -z ${ffwin} ]] ;do
    echo -n .
    sleep .05
done
echo

IFS='+x' read -r width height xpos ypos <<<"$geometry"
xdotool windowraise $ffwin
xdotool windowfocus $ffwin
xdotool windowactivate $ffwin
sleep .8
xdotool windowmove $ffwin $xpos $ypos
xdotool windowsize $ffwin $width $height
xdotool windowactivate $ffwin
sleep .2
xdotool key ctrl+l
xdotool type --delay 22 "$targetUrl"
xdotool key Return
```

Save this in a script, then run them with an url as argument.

You could replace `--new-window` by `--private-window` if needed.

Nota: I use a 48 random chars string as *bound* to force firefox to *title* this string in order to ensure `wmctrl` will find only **this** window...

#### For strictly answering about *size of x% of display size*:

You could replace 4th line:

```
geometry=1200x900+200+120
```

by either:

```
psize=40
while IFS=' +x' read cmd a b c d ;do
    [[ $cmd == -geometry ]] &&
        geometry=$((a*psize/100))+$((b*psize/100))+$c+$d
done  < <(xwininfo -root)
```

or even...

```
psize=40
ar=('')
while IFS=' x+' read dev stat a b c d e f; do
    if [[ $stat == connected ]]; then
        typ=sec
        [[ $a == primary ]] &&
            typ=${a::3} a=$b b=$c c=$d d=$e
        printf '%3d: %s (%s)\n' ${#ar[@]} $dev $typ
        ar+=($((a*psize/100))+$((b*psize/100))+$c+$d)
    fi
done < <(xrandr)
read -p 'Wich display: ' -rsn 1 userKey
if [[ ${ar[userKey]} ]]; then
    geometry=${ar[userKey]}
    echo $userKey
else
    echo user abort
    exit 1
fi
```

You may find [a full version on my site (not on github;)](https://f-hauri.ch/vrac/soFirefox.sh.txt) using `getopts` for

```
Usage: soFirefox [-h] [ -g str | [ [ -p int | [-x int] [-y int] ] [-d str] [URL]
    -d str  Display either 'HDMI-1', 'DP-2', 'secondary', 'root' or 'primary'.
    -g str  Geometry string in format 'WxH+X+Y' (must be alone).
    -h      Show this.
    -p int  Percent of display.
    -x int  Percent width of display.
    -y int  Percent height of display.
    URL     Default to 'https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3A1765658+firefox'.
```

You can run:

```
soFirefox -d primary -y 80 -x 60 https://stackoverflow.com/a/75327166/1765658
```

Comment: In new versions of firefox, I have to click in url and hit `Return` for make firefox execute 1st request.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a suggestion for a script without awk:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ $# -ne 1 ] || ! [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || [ $1 -lt 1 ]; then
  echo "usage: $(basename $0) <number greater 0>"
  exit 1
fi

# Get the display size
resolution=$(xrandr | grep '*' | tr -s ' ' | cut -d ' ' -f2)
display_width=$(echo "$resolution" | cut -d 'x' -f1)
display_height=$(echo "$resolution" | cut -d 'x' -f2)


# Calculate the window size depending on the given command line argument
window_width=$(echo "($display_width * $1)/100" | bc)
window_height=$(echo "($display_height * $1)/100" | bc)

# Open a new instance of Firefox with the calculated size
firefox --width $window_width --height $window_height &

# Open a new tab in the existing instance of Firefox
# see also: https://askubuntu.com/a/1123804
firefox --new-tab --url about:newtab &
```

Note, in my testing I found that if a Firefox window is already open, the size of the already open window is used. The `--width` and `--height` parameters are then ignored.